# Angular2 Child component destroyed unexpectedly in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, components, this, ngfor

So i have this Component of a from with an `@Output` event that trigger on submit, as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    templateUrl: './SomeComponent.html'
})
export class SomeComponent{    
    @Input() data: any;
    @Output() onSubmit: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

    submitForm(): void{
        this.someService.updateBackend(this.data, ()=>{
            this.onSubmit.emit();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using an `ngFor` to create multiple elements of this Component :

```
<template let-data ngFor [ngForOf]="dataCollection">
    <some-component  [data]="data" (onSubmit)="doSomthing()"></some-component>
</template>
```

The last missing part is the service used on submitting:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{

    constructor() {}

    updateBackend(data: any, callback: () => void): void{
        /*
         * updating the backend
         */.then((result) => {
            const { errors, data } = result;

            if (data) {
                callback();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

At the beginning of the `submitForm()` function, the `this.onSubmit.observers` is an Array containing one observer, like it should be.

As soon as it reaches the callback method, where the `this.onSubmit.emit()` is invoked, the `this.onSubmit.observers` is an Array containing ZERO observers.

### I'm experiencing two very weird behaviors:

- If i remove the actual calling to update the backend in `SomeService.updateBackend` it works perfectly fine, and the `observers` still is an Array containing one observer!
- If i keep the actual calling to the backend BUT not using `ngFor` and displaying only one `<some-element>` it also works perfectly fine, keeping one observer in the `this.onSubmit.observers` within the callback scope!

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

### Update:

Thanks to @StevenLuke's comment about logging the `ngOnDestroy` of `SomeComponent` I found out that it is being destroyed before the emit.

Actually, the first thing it is doing when the `SomeService.updateBackend` finishes is Destroying all the instances of this component and recreate them!

This is what makes the observers change! Why would that happen?

Comment: I would suggest to change title to something that reflects the question. `this` doesn't change at all. It is the same object. Output event listeners in ngFor do.

Comment: I will update the title as you suggested, and yes, `dataCollection` is fetched by this service right at the beginning. the `doSomthing` function actually just refetches the data

Comment: @JohnSiu using RC6

Comment: RC6, there should be no "providers" in '@Component', that is moved to '@NgModule'

Comment: @JohnSiu Edited my question, still the same results, any ideas?

Comment: Any chance the subscriber to the event is unsubscribing by the time the response from the backend update is called?  For example, does the submit redirect to another component, so this component is unloaded?

Comment: @StevenLuke I'm not sure why would an unsubscribing happen. This specific component is actually a Modal with a form in it, and when clicking the submit **AFTER** the emit the modal closes, does that count as redirecting components?

Comment: @StevenLuke also note I mentioned it works fine if it is calling the backend but not in `ngFor`

Comment: I saw that it works with a single child.  The difference would be the amount of work that has to be done during the submit, so the response could come back faster.  You are saying that you click submit, and the event you emit causes the modal to disappear, but if the emit doesn't occur the modal stays in place, right?  If so, then it probably isn't my suggestion.  Would be worth adding some logging to ngOnDestroy() to be sure.

Comment: @StevenLuke Clarification: the closing of the modal is statement that comes right after the emit. and it will execute them both, one after the other. Thanks to your advise about logging in the `ngOnDestroy` I found out that the modal is being destroyed REGARDLESS m closing statement. Actually, the first thing it is doing when the `SomeService.updateBackend` finishes is Destroying all the instances of this component and recreate them! This is what makes the `observers` change! Why would that happen?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer (Please note my last comment to StevenLuke) Googling a bit i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 , it might be related but it seems like im unable to understand how to do it, it looks like you've been a part of the conversation, i figured you might be able to help me

Comment: If `dataCollection` is replaced by a different instance, `*ngFor` recreates the whole list of components. You might want to move data to a shared service that outlives recreation by `*ngFor`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What you mean is that because `dataCollection` has changed, the `*ngFor` rerenders and therefore the child components destroy? i'll dive into it and let you know if that's it

Comment: If `dataCollection` has changed, especially when it's a new instance, not only added or removed entries, then I'm pretty sure this is the case.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I see, what is the proper way to place the data in a shared service to "outlive recreation by `*ngFor`"?

Comment: To add it to a service that is provided at a component that doesn't get recreated. Where you add the provider defines the scope where the instance is shared. If you want a singleton for the whole application, provide it in the `AppModule` otherwise on a common parent that doesn't get recreated during the lifetime where you want to keep that instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Alright, ill try implementing your suggestion and update as soon as I'm done

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I wanted to thank you for getting my in the right direction. it did occur because the `dataCollection` changed and triggered the rerendering of the `ngFor`. In my particular case, the data was already on a service but it was connected to a server so doing as you suggested was not the solution, I did solve it in a way that fits to my application. I would really appreciate if you could find a few minutes to write an answer to this post so I could upvote and accept it for the next lookers :)

Comment: Umm, if you just write an answer yourself, I guess this would fit better to your question because you know exactly what needed to be fixed. I guess there are enough other possiblilities where you can upvote an answers of mine ;-)

Comment: When the observable replaces the array `*ngFor` iterates over, then `*ngFor` has to update the view to reflect the change in the model. If you only add or remove items then `*ngFor` also just adds removes the related elements in the DOM.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer And since my `doSomething()` was actually refetching the data from the backend, it was replacing the bound `dataCollection` and caused complete reinitializing of the `ngFor`

Comment: Sorry, I just saw what you changed in your question. Your answer contains that already :D

Comment: You are so active lol, well 118K reputation doesn't fall from the skies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @GünterZöchbauer comments I found out the case was that the data the `ngFor` is bound to was being replaced by a new instance as I updated the backend, hence, it rerendered it's child Components causing reinitializing (destory + init) of them, which made the instance of the Component to be overwritten.

In order to solve this issue i had to place the `dataCollection` in a separate service, getting it for the parent component `ngOnInit`, saving it from causing a rerender of the `ngFor`, and fetch its data again only after the execution of the Child Components ended

Hope it'll be helpful to somebody!

Answer (score 11):

If you provide a trackBy function in your *ngFor to identify items in your dataCollection, it will not destroy and init. Your template would be:

```
<some-component *ngFor="let data of dataCollection;trackBy:trackByFunction"
  [data]="data" (onSubmit)="doSomthing()"></some-component>
```

And the trackByFunction would look like:

```
trackByFunction(index, item) {
    return item ? item.id : undefined;
}
```

So even though an item in your dataCollection is a fresh object, if its id matches an id in the previous collection, *ngFor will update [data] but not destroy and init the component.

Comment: Sounds simple, not sure how didnt that come up at the beginning! :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You saved me so many hours of research. Thank you.